# Working with ArrayList and Reversing files

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently stuck on what to do with my code. I must open a file and then inside of a while loop I have to get each line one at a time then I must reverse it then print it. 
This is what I have so far:

```
 public class ReverseFileContents
  { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
      Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner (new File("reverse"));
      while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
      {
      }
    }
  }
```

This is all I have after this point I am lost and just don't know which direction to go with the arraylist and using BufferedReader. Could anybody help me further this along?

Comment: `reverse` isn't a proper file name. So you're going to have trouble there.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll change that. Any other suggestions regarding arraylist and printing out the file line by line?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to use an ArrayList? Are you planning on doing something with that data later or do you only want it printed backwards?

Comment: This is an assignment I am having problems on. My professor wants an arraylist to be used as of right now. all we are doing is printing the lines for them to be revealed in the correct way.

Comment: Where is the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a homework assignment, and so I'm going to avoid giving you the algorithm you need.

Here are some tips about getting a file and going through it line by line:

```
File filename = new File("file.txt");
Scanner file = new Scanner(filename);

ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    String line = file.nextLine();
    //You can manipulate the line in here and do whatever you want
    //This can also store the data into an ArrayList for later if you need
    myReverse(line);
    lines.add(line);
}
```

Here is a starting point for a reverse method. There are dozens of ways to accomplish this task:

```
public void myReverse(){
    //convert the string into an array
    //move through the array backwards printing the values
}
```

Comment: Thank you I just needed some kind of guidance.

Comment: @user3416645 no problem. If this was what you were looking for, be sure to accept it as the answer. Accepting SOME answer is just as important as asking questions on StackOVerflow.

Answer (score 1):

This will do i believe..!!

```
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
 while (in.hasNextLine()){
System.out.println(reverse(in.nextLine()));
}
```

---

```
public String reverse(String text){
String reverse="";
for( int i = text.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) 
       reverse = reverse + text.charAt(i);;
return reverse;
}
```

Comment: This looks good but I can't use .reverse for this. Sorry I didn't mention that earlier.

Comment: and you must use what ?? custom code to reverse..??

Comment: Yes I have to use my own code or put it into the code somewhere  this is an assignment that I am having troubles with.